# Case Insensitive Search in MongoDB - no Regex and no toLower(), toUpper()

Tags: mongodb, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have researched into this and I found 2 solutions to it:

1. Using regex, which does not use the index and is very slow for my application.
2. Create a duplicate field using tolower() or toUpper(), which again is not the ideal solution in my case as my dataset is huge.

Are there any other solutions to this problem ?

Comment: Closing as dupe, even though the question is "are there any answers *other* than this" because the answer seems to be no.

Comment: @SomeKittens If the answer is no then it is not a duplicate since the linked answer does not answer this question